# Receiving cURL error : Empty reply from server

Tags: php, node.js, curl, hapi.js

I wondered about this as I'm calling one of node js API using cURL from the PHP script, I did `console.log()` on the server and it shows received the payload and the returned response as below but in my PHP script it shows cURL error as `Empty reply from server`

PHP code:

```
$payload = json_encode(array('message_id' => 'test'));
  $ch = curl_init(URL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)));
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
  $response   = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
  $curl_err   = curl_error($ch);
  $info       = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Server response:

```
{ message_id: 'test' }
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `messagenumbermaster` AS `messagenumbermaster` WHERE `messagenumbermaster`.`messagenumber` = 'test';
```

in then returned value: New

I also received a `[http_code] => 0` in `curl_getinfo()`
I searched a lot but there was no luck, please help me.

Node js code:

```
module.exports.checkDuplicate = {

  auth: false,
  validate: {
    payload: joi.object().required().keys({
      message_id: joi.string().required()
    })
  },
  handler: ((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.payload);
    try {
      return emailrdb.messagenumbermaster.count({
        where: {
          messagenumber: req.payload.message_id
        }
      })
      .then(count => {
        console.log('in then');
        if(count > 0){
          //duplicate
          console.log('resturned value: duplicate');
          return 'duplicate';
        }else{
          console.log('resturned value: New');
          return 'New';
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("checkDuplicate: ErrorLog", err);
      Log.createLog(`${new Date()}- checkDuplicate error: ${err}`);
      throw boom.boomify(err.message);
    }
  })
};
```

I received response when tried from RESTer.
Note : I'm running both PHP and Node from localhost

Comment: in fact php code is correct, please add nodejs code how You respond to request?

Comment: @num8er please see node js code

Comment: which framework? is it hapi?

Comment: I'm using hapi js

Comment: I've answered, fix Your nodejs code, You cannot reach to outer scope by doing `return` from internal scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You're calling `return 'New';` from different scope You're returning from `then...` but hapi handler still waits for return that not being called.

You cannot reach to outer scope by doing `return` from internal scope.

So check this code:

```
module.exports.checkDuplicate = {

  auth: false,

  validate: {
    payload: {
      message_id: joi.string().required()
    }
  },

  handler: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {message_id} = req.payload;

      const query = {
        where: {
          messagenumber: message_id
        }
      };
      const model = emailrdb.messagenumbermaster;
      const count = await model.count(query);

      // returning json response with fields: payload, message_id, result, duplicate, count
      return res.response({
               payload: req.payload,
               message_id,
               result: (count > 0 ? 'duplicate' : 'new'), 
               duplicate: count > 0, 
               count
             }).code(200);
      // return res({...}).code(200); // for hapi v16
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Got exception during "checkDuplicate" call. Backtrace:', error);
      Log.createLog(`${new Date()} - checkDuplicate error: ${err.message}`);
      throw boom.boomify(err.message);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but getting same error again with `[http_code] => 0`. I think problem is with php. Because it shows success in `console.log()` on server

Comment: try to do request from postman app https://www.getpostman.com/  if it will respond correct then ok, go solve php code. but I'm sure that it's not php issue. You can see in `console.log` of nodejs app that query executed, but You cannot be sure that it has returned to client. Simply run my code, check with postman, add screenshot here.

Comment: @VilasGalave try to directly call hapi methods and define code as in my updated example